# Changing permissions for @everyone, (NOT CHANNEL PERMISSIONS)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to figure out how to change the "VIEW_CHANNELS" permission for the @EVERYONE role so all channels dissapear, because I have it setup where if I tick the "VIEW CHANNELS" permission off, all the channels dissapear, however, all the guides I have found have only been changing permissions for one channel. Same thing for the discord.js website guides, and I am relatively new to coding(ish).

```
const role = guild.roles.cache.get('777629956473356288')
Role.updateOverwrite(role, { VIEW_CHANNELS: false }).catch((error) => console.log(error))
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Guild.roles.everyone`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=everyone) to get the `@everyone` role of a [`Guild`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Guild).